# Generate TypeScript type with setters from type without setters

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm creating a react application, in which we have a context containing a whole bunch of `useState`s.

In this example, let's pretend there are three.

The context's type comes from a generated data type, looking something like this:

```
type FruitData = {
  banana: string
  apple: number
  tomato: boolean
}
```

The properties need to be individually settable inside the context, so I've made three `useState`s:

```
const [banana, setBanana] = useState<string>("")
const [apple, setApple] = useState<number>(0)
const [tomato, setTomato] = useState<boolean>(false)
```

When I've been annotating the return type of the context, I have so far had to explicitly type it out:

```
type FruitContext = FruitData & {
  setBanana: (value: string) => void
  setApple: (value: number) => void
  setTomato: (value: boolean) => void
}
```

What I'm wondering, if there's any way to automatically generate this type, given the `FruitData` type?

What I have so far:

```
type SetterName = `set${Capitalize<keyof FruitData>}`
type FruitContext = FruitData & {
  [key in SetterName]: (value: any) => void
}
```

This isn't satisfactory, however, because of the `value: any` declaration. I'd like to be able to more cleverly automatically type this property from the `FruitData` type, but I'm not sure if that's possible.

Any tips here?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mAxnPN) solve your problem? If yes, I'll write answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: It does! Make an answer, and I'll accept it! Thanks! PS: You've written "Getters" a couple of places - but I see you mean "Setters".

Comment: Pardon, that was by accident

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help if you didn't have a separate type for the `SetterName` since it is going to be a union, which won't be very useful in our case:

```
type SetterName = `set${Capitalize<keyof FruitData>}`
```

What we really need is to use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) and use [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).

Logic is: we are mapping through keys, remap them and assign value as a setter function:

```
type GetSetters<T> = {
  [K in keyof T & string as `set${Capitalize<K>}`]: (value: T[K]) => void;
};
```

Note: we need `& string` to make sure that we only have string keys, since `Capitalize` utility type only accepts a `string`

Usage:

```
// type Setters = {
//   setBanana: (value: string) => void;
//   setApple: (value: number) => void;
//   setTomato: (value: boolean) => void;
// }

type Setters = GetSetters<FruitData>
```

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/m3vJqN)